# Solving $a(a + 1) + b(b + 1) = 12, (a+ 1)(b+1) = 4$, is there any trick?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, quadratics

What are all (possibly complex) solutions to the following two equations?

$a(a + 1) + b(b + 1) = 12$

$(a+ 1)(b+1) = 4$

Clearly one can substitute the second equation into the first then solve the quartic. But I am wondering if there is a shorter/sneakier way to solve this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $u = a+1, v=b+1$. The equations become

$$(u-1)u+(v-1)v = 12, uv = 4$$

Thus $uv+(u-1)u+uv+(v-1)v = u(v+u-1) + v(u+v-1) = (u+v)(u+v-1) = 20$.

Let $x = u+v$ and we have a quadratic, which yields $u+v = 5$ or $-4$.

Solve the rest using this info and $uv=4$, which is just another quadratic.

---

EDIT: "Solving the quartic" doesn't seem too bad either, by substitution:

$$(u-1)u+\frac4u\left(\frac4u-1\right)=12$$

$$u^2+\frac{16}{u^2}-u-\frac4u=12$$

Note that $\left(u+\frac4u\right)^2=u^2+8+\frac{16}{u^2}$. Hence we can rewrite the above into:

$$\left(u+\frac4u\right)^2 - \left(u+\frac4u\right)=20$$

which, of course, is a quadratic equation with $u+\frac4u = 5$ or $-4$, and thus we arrive at essentially the same conclusion as the above (slightly unnatural) method.

Answer (score 1):

Expressed in elementary symmetric polynomials $s=a+b,p=ab$, the equations become
$$\tag1s^2-2p+s=12$$
$$\tag2p+s=3$$
To get rid of $p$, combine $(1)+2(2)$:
$$s^2+3s=18$$
So either $s=3$ (and $p=0$) or $s=-6$ (and $p=9$). At any rate, $a,b$ are the roots of $x^2-sx+p$, so the solutions are
$$(a,b)=(0,3) \text{or} (3,0) \text{or} (-3,-3).$$

Answer (score 0):

How sneaky would you *like* to be?  If we interpret these expressions as the curve equations $ \ x(x + 1) + y(y + 1) \ = \ 12 \ $ and $ \ ( x + 1)(y+1) \ = \ 4 \ \ , $ we can write the first as the circle equation $ \ \left(x + \frac12 \right)^2 + \left(y + \frac12 \right)^2 \ = \ \frac{25}{2} \ \ $ , with center at $ \ \left(-\frac12 \ , \ -\frac12 \right) \ $ and the second as a "translated" rectangular hyperbola with its center at $ \ (-1 \ , \ -1) \ \ . $  This may not seem helpful initially, but the location of the centers suggests that there is a "diagonal symmetry" for the solutions.

Two of these can be "picked off" by inspection from looking at the intercepts of the curves.  Setting $ \ x \ = \ 0 \ $ gives us $ \ 1·(y + 1) \ = \ 4 \ \Rightarrow \ y \ = \ 3 \ $ for the hyperbola, and we see that this also applies to the circle:  $ \ 0·(0 + 1) + 3·(3 + 1) \ = \ 12 \ \ . $  The symmetry indicates that there is also a solution  $ \ x \ = \ 3 \ , \ y \ = \ 0 \ \ . $  So the two curves intersect one another on the coordinate axes.

Are there any more solutions?  This symmetry about the line $ \ y = x \ $ suggests that we might look at $ \ (x + 1)^2 \ = 4 \ $ and $ \ 2·x(x + 1) \ = \ 12 \ \ . $  The first of these produces $ \ x \ = \ -1 \ \pm \ 2 \ = \ 1 \ , \ -3 \ \ ; \ $  the point $ \ (1 \ , \ 1) \ $ is where the diagonal line meets the hyperbola, but it is certainly *not* on the circle, while the other intersection is $  \ (-3 \ , \ -3) \ \ . $  The intersections of the diagonal line and circle are found from $$ \ x·(x + 1) \ = \ 6 \ \Rightarrow \ x^2 + x - 6 \ = \  (x + 3)·(x - 2) \ = \ 0 \ \ . $$  The point $ \ (2 \ , \ 2) \ $ is not on the hyperbola, but $  \ (-3 \ , \ -3) \  $ definitely *is*.  So the circle, hyperbola, *and* diagonal line *all* meet at $  \ (-3 \ , \ -3) \ \ .  $
The circle and hyperbola in fact just intersect *tangentially* there, which tells us that this solution has an *even* multiplicity.  In regard to the quartic equation you mention and which **player3236** develops (a biquadratic), we can conclude that we have found all four of its solutions:  $ \ (0 \ , \ 3) \ \ , \ \ (3 \ , \ 0) \ \ ,    $ and $ \ (-3 \ , \ -3) \ $ with multiplicity $ \ 2 \ \ . $

[image]

We can check up on this by using the "rotated" coordinates $ \ u \ = \ x + y \ , \ v \ = \ x - y \ \ , $ which transform the curve equations into $ \ u^2 + 4u - v^2 \ = \ 12 \ , \ u^2 + 2u + v^2 \ = \ 24 \ \ . $  Adding these together yields
$$ 2u^2 \ + \ 6u \ - 36 \ \ = \ \ 2·(u + 6)·(u - 3) \ \ = \ \ 0 \ \ . $$
Solving each of the transformed curve equations for $ \ v^2 \ $ gives us
$$ v^2 \ \ = \ \ u^2  +  4u  -  12 \ \ = \ \ (u + 6)·(u - 2) \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ u \ = \ -6 \ \rightarrow \ v^2 \ = \ 0 \ \ , \ \  u \ = \ 3 \ \rightarrow \ v^2 \ = \ 9 $$
and
$$ v^2 \ \ = \ \ 24  -  u^2  -  2u  \ \ = \ \ -(u + 6)·(u - 4) \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ u \ = \ -6 \ \rightarrow \ v^2 \ = \ 0 \ \ , $$ $$  u \ = \ 3 \ \rightarrow \ v^2 \ = \ 9 \ \ . $$
So we find three solution points:
$$ (u \ , \ v) \ \rightarrow \ \left(x = \frac{u + v}{2} \ , \ y = \frac{u - v}{2} \right) \ : \ \ \ (3 \ , \ 3 ) \ \rightarrow \ (3 \ , \ 0 ) \ \ , \ \ (3 \ , \ -3 ) \ \rightarrow \ (0 \ , \ 3 ) \ \ , $$
$$ (-6 \ , \ 0 ) \ \rightarrow \ (-3 \ , \ -3 ) \ \ . $$